# Preview and Simulator looks different Swiftui

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have something like that for the first time. The preview and the simulator do not look identical. I really have no idea how to fix it. Normally the simulator and the preview should be identical?

But it may be that I've nested something but I don't know what exactly.

The images and code are below:

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs0I4.jpg)

[Preview Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G3zz.png)

```
var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        
        Image("bg-official")
            .resizable()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            Text("NUMBER MATCH")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.title)
            GeometryReader { (geometry : GeometryProxy) in

                
                ZStack {
                    
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("bg-roundedrectangle"))
                        .frame(width: 295, height: 310)
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 3){
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 3) {
                            
                            Button {
                                
                            } label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: geometry.size.height/5.5)
                                        .cornerRadius(radius: 20, corners: [.topLeft])
                                    
                                    Text("60 Seconds")
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Button {
                                
                            } label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: geometry.size.height/5.5)
                                        .cornerRadius(radius: 20, corners: [.topRight])
                                    
                                    Text("Endless")
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        HStack(spacing: 3) {
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Button {
                                
                            } label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(Color.white)
                                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: geometry.size.height/5.5)
                                        .cornerRadius(radius: 20, corners: [.bottomLeft])
                                    
                                    Text("Game Center")
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Button {
                                withAnimation() {
                                    sheetManager.present(with: .init(
                                        systemName: "info",
                                        title: "Game Info",
                                        content: "The aim of this game is to match as many tiles as you can with the same number and earn points. Tap a tile to select it and tap another tile with matching number of the first tile you tapp  ed. Be careful and quick; the game will end if you tap a wrong tile, if the timer runs out or if th board gets filled by tiles!"))
                                }
                            } label: {
                                ZStack {
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(Color.white)
                                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: geometry.size.height/5.5)
                                        .cornerRadius(radius: 20, corners: [.bottomRight])
                                    
                                    Text("Game Info")
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.9))
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .popup(with: sheetManager)
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: You compare different geometries (in preview it is full-screen, in simulator some kind of partial-screen pane), so your concern is incorrect. Taking into account how many hardcoded "magical numbers" you have in code there is no surprise here.

Comment: What should I change then?

Comment: It's not all the time, but there are times that simulator and preview do not behave in the same way, so try running the app in simulator because it is the closest to real device exp.

Comment: But how can I solve the problem? To this I added a new view and it's the same